# R Source file location problem while using testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I'm trying to setup the testthat unit test framework and having some trouble to get the source file location right.

My package folder structure is like below:

```
.\R\abc.R
.\R\def.R
.\tests\testthat\test_01.R
```

In my test case file test_01.R, I need to import abc.R. I managed to get this working by specifying a relative path like below:

```
'../../R/abc.R'
```

Now the abc.R file can be sourced successfully from my test cases. However, it failed at the step where abc.R tries to source def.R. I think this is because the working directory is set to ./tests/testthat by testthat.

The fix I can think of is to add a relative path '../../R/' to def.R, but this looks to me like a terrible solution as it will break when I run abc.R directly. And also there are a lot more files like abc.R and def.R in my package.

Is there a more graceful way to handle this?

Sorry if this is a straightforward question as I'm still new to R.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you're doing, but it sounds like you're trying to access the package source files directly. Don't do that. A package should be treated as a self-contained, opaque blob. You talk to it via its exported functions/objects, and you test it by running those functions and seeing if they do what they're supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Inside ./tests/ there should be a file named *testthat.R*

Within this file you can add 3 lines:

```
library(testthat)
library(yourLibraryName)

test_check("yourLibraryName")
```

Of course replace "yourLibraryName" with the name of your package.

Then all the functions exported by your package will be loaded and tests will be able to use them.